# What counts as modification?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, concurrentmodification

I'm relatively new to multi-threading, and I am trying to use 3 different threads in a game I'm creating. One thread is performing the back end updating, another is being used for the drawing, and the third is to load and/or generate new chunks (and soon to save them down when I don't need them). I had the draw and update threads working just fine, then when I added the third thread into the mix, I started to get problems with ConcurrentModificationExceptions. They are occurring inside my for ... all loops, in which I am looping through an ArrayList of chunk objects.

I have tried to lock down when each thread is able to access and modify the chunk ArrayList using a Phaser as follows:

```
private volatile ArrayList<Chunk> chunks = new ArrayList<Chunk>();
private volatile int chunksStability = 0; //+'ive = # threads accessing, -'ive = # threads editing
private volatile Object chunkStabilityCountLock = new Object();
private volatile Phaser chunkStabilityPhaser = new Phaser() {
    protected boolean onAdvance(int phase, int registeredParties) {
        synchronized(chunkStabilityCountLock)
        {
            if (registeredParties == 0)
            {
                chunksStability = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                chunksStability = Math.max(Math.min(chunksStability*-1, 1), -1);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};

//...

/**
 *  Prevents other threads from editing <b>World.chunks</b>. 
 *  Calling this will freeze the thread if another thread has called <b>World.destabalizeChunks()</b>
 *  without calling <b>World.stabalizeChunks()</b>
 */
public void lockEditChunks()
{
    chunkStabilityPhaser.register();
    if (this.chunkStabilityPhaser.getUnarrivedParties() > 1 && this.chunksStability < 0) //number threads currently editing > 0
    {
        this.chunkStabilityPhaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance(); //wait until threads editing finish
    }

    synchronized(chunkStabilityCountLock)
    {
        ++this.chunksStability;
    }
}
public void unlockEditChunks()
{
    chunkStabilityPhaser.arriveAndDeregister();
}

/**
 *  Prevents other threads requiring stability of <b>World.chunks</b> from continuing 
 *  Calling this will freeze the thread if another thread has called <b>World.lockEditChunks()</b>
 *  without calling <b>World.unlockEditChunks()</b>
 */
public void destabalizeChunks()
{
    chunkStabilityPhaser.register();
    if (this.chunkStabilityPhaser.getUnarrivedParties() > 1 && this.chunksStability > 0) //number threads currently editing > 0
    {
        this.chunkStabilityPhaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance(); //wait until threads editing finish
    }

    synchronized(chunkStabilityCountLock)
    {
        --this.chunksStability;
    }
}
public void stabalizeChunks()
{
    chunkStabilityPhaser.arriveAndDeregister();
}
```

However, I still haven't had any success. I'm wondering if perhaps the reason I am getting a concurrent modification exception has to do with that I might be making modifications to the actual Chunk objects. Would this count as modification, and result in a ConcurrentModificationException. I do know that I am not performing the modification within the same thread, since the exception is not consistently thrown. Leading me to believe that the error is only occurring when one thread (I don't know which) reaches a specific point in its execution while another is iterating through the chunks ArrayList.

I know the simple solution would be to stop using the for ... all loops, and instead perform the loop manually as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < chunks.size(); ++i)
{
    Chunk c = chunks.get(i);
}
```

However, I am concerned that this will result in occasional twitchy behaviour on screen when chunk objects are shifted around in the arraylist. I don't want to synchronize access to it entirely across all threads because that would hinder performance, and this may turn out to be a fairly large project, requiring maximum efficiency where possible. Additionally I don't have any reason to prevent 2 threads from modifying the Chunk ArrayList if they don't use an iterator or require it's stability, nor do I have any reason to prevent 2 threads from iterating through the list simultaneously when nothing is modifying it.

More complete copies of relevant files:

[World.java](http://ideone.com/n3j9yr)
[Chunk.java](http://ideone.com/pkMwjN)

[WorldBuilder.java](http://ideone.com/qxwiA5)
[ChunkLoader.java](http://ideone.com/rnqIE0)

Comment: You should consider immutable objects.

Comment: 0another way, again depending on the logic might be to have a loop on a copy: final Chunk[] copy = chunks.toArray(new Chunk[0]); for( Chunk c : copy ). It might be fine in your case, or might be completely wrong and you have to check who and why modify the list

Comment: I get the feeling that you don't really appreciate all the consequences of concurrent access. Are you saying that you modify the arraylist with no locking whatsoever? This is not just about interleaved actions of threads, it is about completely disfiguring the internal invariants of the arraylist. It is about threads never finding out what other threads did to it. You really should read up on the Java Memory Model.

Comment: no, I'm not saying I modify the ArrayList without any locking. The phaser is being used as a lock. I am trying to allow threads iterating to run concurrently with other threads iterating, but not with threads modifying, and threads modifying run concurrently with other threads modifying, but not with threads iterating. Ie. If I have threads already modifying, threads iterating should wait, if I have threads iterating, threads modifying should wait.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should make your code so fast, that you can load chunks in between frames. You should be able design this so the pauses do not take more than couple milliseconds and everything still runs smooth. This way your users get quickly loaded chunks and you do not have to deal with multithreaded code and chase race conditions.

If it turns out you absolutely have to use threads, limit to minimum mutable state shared between them. Ideally you would have two queues, one with load request and one with loaded levels. Those two queues should be the only way those threads communicate. Once some object is sent to another thread, origin thread should no longer use it in any way. This way you can avoid race conditions without adding synchronization.

---

To more directly answer your question: `ConcurrentModificationException` occurs only if you modify the collection. Modifying elements stored inside it doesn't affect the list itself.

I highly suspect you have something wrong with your synchronization code. It looks needlessly complicated. In current form only one thread should access `chunks` at a time. Other have to wait for their turn. [Phaser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) is definitively unnecessary in this case. It's a job for simple synchronized block or, in worst case, read-write lock.

Comment: `Phaser` is a JDK class.

Comment: I tried to use a read write lock, I just couldn't find a clean way of getting it so that multiple threads could be reading or writing at the same time, just not let threads do both. any suggestions?

Comment: You cannot allow two threads to write at the same time. This won't result in `CME` but might corrupt your collection. The default behavior of [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) is exactly what you want.

Comment: I can't have to threads adding elements to an ArrayList at the same time? Why not?

Comment: See the documentation. [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) doesn't support it. If two threads add elements to the same ArrayList, the result is undefined. Usually you will lose some of the elements.